# How can I post an image to slack from a proxy?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have an image that is hosted through a corporate proxy on a private network.
I want to post this image as an accessory on slack via a block.

```py
            blocks=[
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": response
                    },
                    "accessory": {
                        "type": "image",
                        "image_url": "http://unaccesible_website/files/14619.png",
                        "alt_text": "User's picture"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

When I try to access this image, I get an error telling me that `{'messages': ['[ERROR] downloading image failed [json-pointer:/blocks/0/accessory/image_url]']}}`which I can only assume is because slack cannot access the image through the corporate proxy. (I have no problem accessing it from my browser when I am in the corporate network).

My question is, how do I tell slack to go get the image through the proxy?

I have a workaround for this right now that involves downloading the image on my local hard drive and then uploading it with files_upload, but this is slow, and stops me from using blocks (so far I haven't found a way to upload a file in a block).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?